# Does the matrix span the given plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to figure out if the following matrix will span the plan given by $-7x + 14y - 7z = 0$

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 11\\
2 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & -2 & -9
\end{pmatrix}$$

I think they way to go about this problem is to find if the vector $[-7, 14, -7]$ is in the column space of the matrix. Is that right? What's the reasoning behind this?

My second guess is to see if the vector $[-7, 14, -7]$ is in the nullspace of $A.$ My intuition behind this is because I see that on one side of the plane equation there's a zero.

Answer (score 1):

Just check two things:

1. Are $\alpha_1 = (1, 2, 3), \alpha_2 = (4, 1, -2), \alpha_3 = (11, 1, -9)$ falling in the plane $-7x + 14y - 7z = 0$?
2. What is the rank of $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3\}$ (i.e., the rank of $A$)? Note the dimension of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $2$.